# How can div with be controlled with responsiveness

Tags: html, css, responsiveness

I  have a div with width 364px. There can be one or more same divs inside the container. I want divs width to behave like following.

I want to show maximum 4 div in one row, which i am doing right now. What i want is, if there is one div its width should 100%. if two divs, it should be 50 50 %. If three divs, then width should be 33.3% for each div. If four, then 25% each.

How can i do that?

the container could look like this,

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="goal"></div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="goal"></div>
    <div class="goal"></div>
    <div class="goal"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS is the following but i don't know how can implement such rules

```
.goal {
background: #5A8EAE;
width: 364px;
height: auto;
color: #F4F7F9;
float: left;
margin-right: 20px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flexbox

Your div's need to be all equal width so your rule is: `flex: 1 0 0` which states:

```
flex-grow: 1; /* grow to fill the available space */
flex-shrink: 0; /* can't shrink, but because the default width is 0, it doesn't need to */
flex-basis: 0; /* default width */
```

and set `display:flex` on `.container`.

```css
.goal {
background: #5A8EAE;
width: 364px;
height: auto;
color: #F4F7F9;
float: left;
margin-right: 20px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  flex: 1 0 0;
  -ms-flex: 1 0 0;
  -webkit-flex: 1 0 0;
}

.container {
  display:flex;
  display:-ms-flex;
  display:-webkit-flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="goal">1</div>
    <div class="goal">2</div>
    <div class="goal">3</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="goal">1</div>
    <div class="goal">2</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="goal">1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please explain a bit this flex value? 1 0 0 ?

Comment: It means that the `.goal` should all start out at `0` width (the third 0) and should grow as necessary (the first 1), all on the same line, no wrapping, making them all equal width. This is the best guide I've found and I refer to it often: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @Shaonline please keep in mind that IE 10 or below has issues with `display: flex` http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: @AGE - it supports an older syntax, but it fully supports flexbox.

Comment: @Adam agreed, go ahead and add the syntax to your answer... or a link for reference

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved also without flexbox using `display: table` and `display: table-cell`

Html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="goal">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="goal">1</div>
    <div class="goal">2</div>
    <div class="goal">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="goal">1</div>
    <div class="goal">2</div>
    <div class="goal">3</div>
    <div class="goal">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.wrapper {
  width: 350px;
}
.container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.goal {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: table-cell;
  background: #5A8EAE;  
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/stilllife00/pen/OyQbom)

Answer (score 0):

a jquery solution if you're willing to use jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.add').on('click', function() {
        if ($('.goal').length < 4) {
            $('.container').append('<div class="goal">stuff here</div>');
            responsive();
        }
    });
    
    responsive();
 function responsive() {
     var count = $('.goal').length;
        var width = parseFloat(100.00/count).toFixed(0) - 1;
        $('.goal').each(function() {
         $(this).css('width', width + '%');
        });
    };
});
```

```css
.container {
    width: 364px;
    background: lightgray;
    outline: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 15px;
}
.goal {
    outline: 1px solid black;
    height: 50px;
    background: gray;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="add" href="#">ADD DIV</a>

<div class="container">
    <div class="goal">stuff here</div>
</div>
```